# Royal favours in Caylus

Tags: caylus

1. When building a prestige building by using the 4th row of the royal favours table (e.g. after winning a royal favour as the player who built the most houses on the castle) that gives you more favours, is it permitted to use these very favours to construct another buidling? In other words, is it considered "building" the blue building, part of the same phase? I know that in general, during the same phase you're not allowed to use the same row.
2. Let's say I've already placed my marker at the first column of the 4th row at the royal favours table. After I win another favour, am I allowed to advance my pawn to the 2nd column, even if I don't have the materials to build a wooden building?

Comment: You appear to be asking multiple questions which would be easier to answer in separate questions.

Comment: I was not sure whether I should do it separetely, since they are kind of related. Will keep it in mind though, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rules reference [here](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=711)

1)  No, you may not build another building.  As you are aware the rules say: -

> If a player gains several favors during the same phase (for
>   instance, during a count or when the monument is built), the
>   favors must be used on different lines. So, it is impossible
>   to gain more than 4 favors in a phase.

You gained the favour allowing you to build in phase 6, building the castle.  If you build a building that give you more favours the phase has not changed.

2) Yes,  You advance your marker unless prevented by the stage of the game (ie building the keep, walls etc).

> Whenever a player earns a favor, they must choose a line at
>   once, and, if it is possible, advance their marker to the right.
>   Then, the player can use one of the effects provided on the
>   chosen line, between level 1 and the level currently indicated
>   by the marker.

The restriction on moving the marker is the stage of the game, not if you are able to carry out the action.  Don't forget when moving on the favour track you don't have to carry out the action you move to, you can select any of the action you passed on that row.  Also if you are the end of the row you can still keep selected that row and carrying out any action.

Comment: Reagrding 2: So we can justify it by saying that I advance my marker and I "choose" to use the 1st column which is practically empty?

Comment: Yes thats absolutely fine.  or you could advance on the cube track up to the purple cube and choose to take the pink cube.   you can choose to do nothing.  You only don't advance if crossing the double lines is prohibited by what 3rd of game your in.